# @valid annotation sends exception in response to rest service

Tags: java, rest, validation, jakarta-ee

I am using custom validation in my rest web services.

```
@PUT
    @Path("/{accountId}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response update(
            @NotNull @ValidUUID @PathParam("accountId") UUID accUUID,
            @NotNull @Valid Account changedAcc) {
        synchronized (LOCK_MANAGER.getLock(accUUID)) {
            return accHelper.update(this.getCurrentUser(), accUUID, changedAcc);
        }
    }
```

here is a glimpse at my Account class

```
@Table(keyspace = "Randomss", name = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "acc_type")
    @NotNull
    @ValidString
    @JsonIgnore
    private String accType;
```

Now I send JSON data to this web service to update account,
but if I send some wrong json data
(e.g acc_type is expected as string and I send numeric data)
then it throws an exception.

How do I get it to send an error message instead of throwing an exception
(specifically, I want to send the error message)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a *[javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html)* that implements an *[javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)*.

For example a generic `ValidationExceptionMapper` might look like:

```
@Provider
public class ValidationExceptionMapper
                    implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    public Response toResponse(ValidationException e) {
        return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

}
```

You can choose a more appropriate response to return.